# Cancel Transition animation on Activity destroy

Tags: java, android

I have a splash screen that goes to my main activity and uses a transition animation.

I want to know how to stop the animation if I 'swipe' the application from my app list. Currently if I do this you will still see the animation on top of my phone's home screen.

Splash screen:

```
    intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    finish();
```

I have tried some of these, but with no success:

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

or

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

or

```
finish();
```

etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: remove setFlags line and check

Comment: If I do that the animation will not play at all.

Comment: is it? animation works without flags i think

Comment: @srinu cannot get the animation to work without those flags. Guess I need them.

Comment: you need the animation or you don't need it ? be clear.

Comment: @Sam I need it. But I want it so that if I swipe the app from the app tray, during the animation, the animation stops. Which it does not as it is.

Comment: @Skromak Have you followed the Android [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) ?

Comment: @vincrichaud Yes but it assumes you are using a View, which I am not, unless I am mistaken.